# BIOS freezes when trying to boot from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS live-usb

Tags: boot, live-usb

## The problem

Desktop PC **freezes** completely at **BIOS boot up** when trying to boot from  **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS USB stick**.

## How I made the USB

Using **Startup Disc Creator** application which comes installed by default in **Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.4 LTS (laptop)** and **ElementaryOS Loki (desktop in question)**.

## Other things I've tried

- Booting from **Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS** and **14.04 LTS** also **freezes at boot up**.
- Creating the **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS USB** stick with **UNetbootin** but also **fails**. However, it doesn't freezes, it just reports "**Missing Operating System**".
- Booting from **ElementaryOS Loki USB stick**. It **works**!
- Using **GParted** to compare how the USB was formatted by **Startup Disc Creator** with the **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** and **ElementaryOS Loki**.

With **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** made with **Startup Disc Creator**:

```
|Partition   |File system |Size        |Used        |Unused      |Flags      |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
|/dev/sdc1   |unknown     |4.00 KiB GiB|         ---|         ---|           |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
|unallocated |unallocated |1.75 GiB    |         ---|         ---|           |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
|/dev/sdc2   |fat16       |2.28 MiB    |2.26 MiB    |20.00 KiB   |           |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
|unallocated |unallocated |27.31 GiB   |         ---|         ---|           |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
```

With **ElementaryOS** Loki made with **Startup Disc Creator**:

```
|Partition   |File system |Size        |Used        |Unused      |Flags      |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
|unallocated |unallocated |2.62MiB     |         ---|         ---|           |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
|/dev/sdc2   |fat16       |2.28 MiB    |2.25 MiB    |28.00 KiB   |esp        |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
|unallocated |unallocated |7.26 GiB    |         ---|         ---|           |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
```

With **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** made with **UNetbootin**:

```
|Partition   |File system |Size        |Used        |Unused      |Flags      |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
|/dev/sdc1   |fat32       |7.22 GiB    |1.85 GiB    |5.37 GiB    |           |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
```

## Possible cause(s)

The problem seems to be related to how the USB is formatted. I'm suspecting it has something to do with the flags. While the **ElementaryOS Loki** live-usb made with **Startup Disc Creator** has a **partition** flagged as **esp**, the **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** one made with either **Startup Disc Creator** or **UNetbootin** doesn't. I think it should be flagged as **boot** but I'm not sure since the **ElemntaryOS** one has **esp**, which I'm not even sure what it means.

## Questioon

¿Should it be flagged as **boot**? And if so, why is not being flagged automatically?

## Other details

- Gigabyte GA-EX58-UD5 motherboard
- BIOS F7
- Sony 8GB USB
- Kingston DTmicroDuo 8GB

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I was able to make the **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS live USB stick** work by creating it with **UNetbootin** and then flagging the partition as **boot** with **GParted**. I will leave the question open, however,  because I would like to know why this is not being done automatically by **UNetbootin** and why it's not even being formatted properly by **Startup Disc Creator**.  Thanks!

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? While FAT16 is allowed on external devices with UEFI, it normally is FAT32. And has the ESP flag which is also boot with UEFI. Grub (BIOS boot) does not use boot flag (Windows does, as does the old Lilo boot loader and syslinux which the installer normally uses for BIOS boot), but some systems will not boot without a boot flag on some partition. ESP - efi system partition. Normally FAT32 on internal drives with boot flag and esp flag if separate. Normally just boot flag required.

Comment: Hi @oldfred. Sorry, I forgot to mention that it's BIOS (it's a 10 years old motherboard). I think this might be the answer: "some systems will not boot without a boot flag on some partition." By the way, l also forgot to mention that Gparted give me warnings about not being able to detect the size properly with the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS live USB made with Startup Disc Creator. Thanks!

Comment: @oldfred, I think your comment has answered my question, so you might want to convert it to an answer so that I can mark it as the best one. Or we can wait to see if anybody else has something else to add. Either way, thanks a lot! I've been struggling with this problem for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions, the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator is a very robust cloning tool, which simply makes an exact copy from the iso file to the USB pendrive. This makes a USB boot drive, that works in most PC computers.

In older Ubuntu versions (for example Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), there are buggy versions of the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator. It is better to use some other tool to create a USB boot drive.

### This particular case

I agree that this might be the answer (originally explained by @oldfred).

> I forgot to mention that it's BIOS (it's a 10 years old motherboard).
>   I think this might be the answer: "some systems will not boot without
>   a boot flag on some partition."

My experience makes me guess that you might have an HP computer. But there might be other brands, that need a boot flag, where other computers won't need it to boot.

- *Please tell us the brand name and model of the computer/motherboard and BIOS system.* It is useful information for other people with the same or similar problems.

If this is the problem, you might succeed, if you

- use [**`mkusb`**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to make a persistent live drive and
- select an msdos partition table (instead of the default gpt)

**`mkusb`** creates a persistent live drive, that boots via `grub` also in BIOS mode. You can boot such a [USB pen] drive live-only, if you do not want or need persistence. I can boot HP computers, that are approximately 10 years old this way.

### Please test mkusb, if you have the time

If you have the time, please test a persistent live drive by mkusb and share the result.

If you run standard Ubuntu *live*, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

[Link to mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Comment: That's a lot of information. Thanks @sudodus! I also added the motherboard model and BIOS version in "Other details" as requested. It's not an HP computer. I built it myself back then but it might be useful to know for those who own one. I also added from which OSes I've tried making the live usb with Startup Disc Creator. I haven't had the time to try mkusb yet but I'll let you know when I do. Hope it helps!

Comment: @AndrésAngelini, 1. Thanks for the data about the motherboard and BIOS. I have no own experience (of that motherboard), but I think the information will be useful for several people; 2. I think the USB boot drives are good (made with a robust version of the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator); 3. I'm looking forward to your results with mkusb :-)

Comment: Hi @sudodus! I finally got the time to test [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).  Bare in mind I did some things a little bit different. Apparently, I didn't need to add **universe** and I didn't install either **mkusb-nox** nor **usb-pack-efi**. I'm not sure what the first one is and I'm not making a persistent drive so the second wasn't necessary in my case. Unfortunately, the results were the same as the ones with **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS stick made with Startup Disc Creator** (first table). It froze completely and it's missing the **boot** flag. Also, it has  four partitions.

Comment: @AndrésAngelini, I would expect that result, when you *clone* with mkusb. It is exactly the same process as with the Ubuntu Startup Disc Creator. But if you create a persistent live drive, mkusb uses an *extracting* method: creates an 'own' partition table with file systems, labels and flags. For full flexibility to select settings you need `usb-pack-efi`, but it may still work without it. *So I suggest that you try once more*, this time creating a persistent live drive, even if you need no persistence. *Try to boot the persistent live drive **live-only** (without persistence).*

Comment: **It works perfectly** by making a **persistent live drive** with **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS iso**  using [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) with **usb-pack-efi** and then booting it as **live-only**! On a closer inspection with **GParted**, I noticed it created 6 partitions with the one formatted as **fat32** flagged as **boot**. So, **_making the live-usb drive as persistent even if you don't need to might be the most straightforward solution for a regular user_** who is experiencing this issue.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @AndrésAngelini, I think you are right (in this particular case and similar cases, where the computer wants a boot partition with a FAT32 file system and a boot flag). I am glad that it works for you, and thanks for testing this method and sharing the result :-)

Comment: Thanks to you too @sudodus! I still think Startup Disc Creator should do this automatically so I'm considering filing a bug report. It might take me a while because I've never done it before.

Comment: @AndrésAngelini, Since the Ubuntu Startup Disc Creator is a cloning tool, the changes you want should be either implemented in the iso files (if possible), or the Startup Disk Creator must be turned back to an extracting tool again (like it was before Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). But the extracting Startup Disc Creator had a sad story with continuous problems during several years due to many bugs, I think mainly because it could not keep up with the modifications of the boot structure in the iso files and upgraded versions of syslinux for booting in BIOS mode.

Comment: That's a great insight, @sudodus. And now that I think about it, the ElementaryOS Loki iso does boot without any hiccups in my desktop pc, which means this could (or should) be solved at the iso level. Perhaps, then, I should file a bug to Ubuntu itself. I feel like I should be doing something to let the developers know the installation iso is not working for some of us.

Comment: If ElementaryOS Loki boots from a cloned USB pendrive, it's a good idea to file a bug about it to Ubuntu (that is at Launchpad). Good luck, @AndrésAngelini :-)

Comment: Will do then. Thanks again @sudodus. I've been awesome.

Answer (score 2):

With BIOS based systems grub does not use Boot flag. But some BIOS must assume Windows and will not boot without some partition having a boot flag on a primary partition. Windows requires a boot flag on a primary NTFS formatted partition to boot.

Live installer in BIOS mode is FAT32 (normally) and needs boot flag on that partition. Some tools (like dd) when used to create live installer, use different methods to create live installer and then it may not look like standard partitions. Not sure which versions, create which type of view from gparted or partition lists.